Name and properties of $\sup_{a \in A}\| P_K(a)-a\|_H$ where $P_K$ is the projection onto a closed convex set $K$
Let $K$ be a closed convex subset of a Hilbert space $H$ and $A \subset H$ be some other set.
Does the following quantity
$$\sup_{a \in A}\| P_K(a)-a\|_H$$
where $P_K\colon H \to K$ is the orthogonal projection, have a name or relations to other concepts, and any interesting properties? Eg. if $A$ is dense in $K$, can we say something about it?

Wouldn’t this just be zero if $A \subset K$? Also, if $K$ is just a close convex set, I wouldn’t call it orthogonal projection. That is usually only used for closed subspaces. (In any case, this is just the distance from $A$ to $K$. So half of the definition of Hausdorff distance.)

I think that it is sometimes called "excess of $A$ over $K$".
